# Iozone record sizes and real-life purpose

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

I am puzzled about `Iozone` record sizes. My questions are:

- how to find out what record size my application uses?;
- what is the correlation between `Iozone` record size and the filesystem `Block Size`?;
- how I can tune my filesystem (ext4) to benefit from certain record size?;

Thanks!

Comment: It's generally encouraged to separate your questions out in separate posts. This way each question is specifically targeted to one specific question, helping those who answer to stay focused and those who will search for the answers to find it quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I think the IOzone term,record size, is similar to avgrq-sz

avgrq-sz: The average size (in 512 Byte sectors) of the requests  that  were issued to the device.

> how to find out what record size my application uses?;

$iostat -x /dev/sdc

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s **avgrq-sz** avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sdc               1.96     1.68    1.33    0.54   274.67   273.13   293.56     0.02    8.61   0.90   0.17

> what is the correlation between Iozone record size and the filesystem Block Size?;

I think, when determining block size, just make sure it is 1/n of record size

> how I can tune my filesystem (ext4) to benefit from certain record size?;

same as above.

In terms of file system peformance, another factor need to be considered, if you use RAID. It is chunk size of raid device

Chunk Size=avgrq-sz/ number of data disks